# The vacuum of spin-1 fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Every QFT text would talk about the vacuum energy of spin-0 and spin-1/2 fields. For spin-0, it is
$$ E_0=\int d^3x \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{2} \omega_p.$$
The vacuum energy of spin-1/2 fields is negative. And this forms part of the theoretical motivation towards supersymmetry.

However, I have never seen any book talking about the vacuum energy of spin-1 fields? If you work out the Hamiltonian, it's basically something like $E^2+B^2$...Does this mean the vacuum energy of spin-1 fields is zero?